# Does pooled sample genotyping microarray analysis exist?

Tags: genomics, microarray, illumina, genotyping, snp-chip

I want to genotype samples in small batches with a common microarray (e.g., the GSA). However, the cost is very high for small batches.

With a higher sample throughput/volume, per sample cost becomes more reasonable as the processing cost for a single run is spread out over more samples.

I'd like to process no more than 16 samples per run, ideally even one or four samples per run. (Being able to submit a single sample for microarray analysis without having to pay to run the rest of the empty chip would be great.)

It is possible that some company or core offers "pooled" microarray services, where I could submit a small number of samples that would be processed with other groups' samples on the same microarray run. This would mean there are more samples per run, so it could potentially cost much less.

Looking on core and company websites, I don't see this offered anywhere.

Does this service exist?

Comment: I understand the question entirely. My personal view is this is primarily a wet-lab question. Companies will do mass chip printing to reduce costs, which are stored. Grouping between independent clients I would suggest is avoided because of the risk of any form of "spill-over". For example, chips get mislabelled and you get someone else's results.  For the company it's a disaster and they lose client confidence. Better to work alongside colleagues with similar aims as you for the "pool".

Comment: The experimental problem with microarrays/chip technology is the variation in quality. Statistically this can be corrected, but wet-lab perspective is they don't like any inclination of sub-optimal quality.

Comment: @M__ Yes, that makes sense. I imagine that's why most cores don't operate like that

Comment: This can also be done at the sender (rather than the chip runner) level. Multiple senders get together to send samples